# Stop the Save As prompt when users make changes then close workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to supress the "Save as" method of going to File > Save as with the below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave _
               (ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If SaveAsUI = True Then Cancel = True

End Sub
```

I have made the file read only, so the "Save" option stops them from saving this way.

However, if they make changes to the sheet the workbook they are prompted to Save their changes. Clicking "Yes" will bring up the "Save As" prompt.

My ultimate goal here is to stop them saving over this sheet or being able to save a copy of the sheet anywhere. I want them to be able to open the sheet, use its functions/features and that is it.

VBA is password protected.

They will access it via a shortcut, the file is not on their machine (I know a local copy is created, this is my next challenge) The file itself will be on a server controlled by Active Directory.

Comment: Your entire work is based on the fact that they activate VBA / macros when opening your file. If they don't execute / allow your code to be run then nothing you program will execute or "protect" your file. Furthermore, you cannot prevent them from opening the file using other apps like [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/) which will bypass macros and some other security mechanisms you might have implemented (like VBA password protection). And these are just some shortcomings. In short: if you ask me, then I'd say there is no real security when you use Excel.

Comment: I will be on the users computer initially to set up Excel and this connection so I will be enabling that myself. I understand Excel isn't bulletproof but the more difficult or off putting I can make it the better. If someone really wants to get hold of it then they will, but the users for this sheet will generally not be IT savvy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that we agree that Excel does not provide any real protection, this is probably what you are looking for:

(1) Make sure that the user does not get a question about saving changes when the file is closed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

(2) Making sure the user cannot print the Excel file:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True

End Sub
```

(3) You can even automatically close the file when it is deactivated to try and make sure that they don't create a new Excel file in which they reference your "protected" file:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

<sub>Please note that you cannot / should not use all subs together as they are partically interdependent. So, if you are closing the file using option (1) with the event `BeforeClose` then the sub `Deactivate` will fail as there is no open Excel file to close anymore (and vice versa).</sub>

Comment: For (1), it closes the workbook fine, but the Excel window behind remains open. How can I close this at the same time?

Comment: In this case you want to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False : ThisWorkbook.Parent.Quit`. Because the `parent` of the Excel file is considered the Excel application showing the given Excel file (especially useful when several instances of Excel are open). The `DisplayAltert` has to be disabled first to ensure that the user does **not** get the question if the file should be saved first.